# Symfony: join request using QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a database model with 2 tables: user and experimentation. Relation is n:n, so I created a third table with the 2 foreign keys.

| Experimentation | 1-------0..n |ExperimentationUser| 0..n-------1 |User|

Entity are generated thanks to Doctrine (with annotations). I got UserEntity and ExperimentationEntity, but not ExperimentationUserEntity. When I look into USerEntity, I can find a collection of "associated experimentation IDs".

I would like to get all experimentation names (not IDs) for a specified User. In common SQL, I'll have join Experimentation and ExperimentationUser with a WHERE clause (for User ID selection). But since I'm starting a Symfony (2.8) project, I'd like to use the QueryBuilder.

I'm not familiar with the syntax and I have no idea of how I can achieve this. What I have tried:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Experimentation');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->join('...')
                    ->setParameter('id',$id)
                    ->getQuery();
```

But I don't know what to put in the `join` clause. I'm not even sure I need it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you show your entities annotated by doctrine? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I do this kind of things. I don't use query builder but you con get the idea.

In the entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Experimentation
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ExperimentationRepository")
 */
class Experimentation
{
 //...
}
```

In the repository class

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ExperimentationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
   public function getExperimentationByUser($id) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e '
        . 'FROM AppBundle:Experimentation e '
        . 'JOIN e.experimentationUsers eu '
        . 'JOIN eu.user u '
        . 'WHERE u.id = :id ')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);

    return $query->getResult();
  }
}
```

Then in controller

```
//..
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Experimentation')->getExperimentationByUser($user_id);
//..
```

In that way you can get the list of experimentation a then get it's name, or also in the query put just `$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e.name '` . If you also need data related to user can put `$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT e, u '` and possibly you can save some database request.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I manage to do something similar but with the Query builder. I'll accept your answer anyway as it seems pretty close to what I got now

Comment: Hi @DavidL, can you mabye post the querybuilder script you've wrote? I think it might help some people (including myself)